# Create database for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

At work, I'm able to connect to several SQL Server databases which I can write code to query from. I would like to be able to have my own database on my own computer at home so that I can practice writing queries.

So according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186312.aspx, the steps that I should follow is:

Using SQL Server Management Studio

To create a database

1. In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine and then expand that instance.
2. Right-click Databases, and then click New Database.

So I'm kind of stuck on step one because I don't have any database / servers/ instances (I may be using the wrong terminology here). How do I get one? I would really appreciate it if someone can give me a high leveled overview of how everything is related.

Comment: If you don't have a server, then what are you connecting to when you open SSMS?

Comment: You first need to install sql server on your home machine. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1) Instal SQL server to your local PC, some help you can find here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-installation-wizard-setup

2) Connect to your SQL server

3) Clicl "New Query" and exec

```
create database test
```

This stmt will create DB with name "test" and default properties